# Blazor Server Application - add or update claim after authentication

Tags: blazor-server-side, claims-based-identity

It is required to add or update claim after user login/authentication.

We are using below code for adding custom claim, **its working fine but when we reload page the previous added claim wont available** or gets removed from Claims Identity.

```
 public static async bool AddUserClaim(this ClaimsPrincipal principal, string name, string value)
    {
        bool isAdded = false;

        var clm = new Claim(name, value);

        ClaimsIdentity ci =(ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

        //REMOVE CLAIM IF EXIST
        if (principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == clm.Type))
        {               
            ci.RemoveClaim(ci.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == clm.Type));                
        }

        //ADD CLAIM WITH UPDATED VALUE
        ci.AddClaim(clm);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the additional claims during the authentication process and before the session cookie with the ClaimsPrincipal user is issued.

For example, if you use the AddOpenIDConnect handler, then it provides various event handlers that you can hook into, especially the OnTokenValidated eventhandler.

This handler is a perfect opportunity to lookup the local user information based on for example the subject (sub) claim in the received ID-token.

I think this blog post [here](https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2) provides a good intoduction on how to do it.